# Auth guard [api] is not defined on Laravel Jetstream register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

So, I just enabled Laravel Jetstream register. When I tried to submit, the model creation work however, the auto-login didn't.

It throws an error saying:

> Auth guard [api] is not defined.

I really don't know why it uses API guard. This is my auth.php

```
 'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

I've been looking for an answer for almost 5 hours now, and still can't make it work.
Tried clearing every cache but to no luck.

What I might be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you use something like `auth:api`  in your route web/api, you should add api guard in your config/auth.php file.

```
'api' =>[
    'driver' => 'token',
    'provider' => 'users'
]
```